# Remote-MTA: dns; [192.168.92.98] private ip elimination

Tags: postfix

I have Postfix installed, Whenever my email bounces back in the header information it is showing private ip (internal infrastructure), which i wanted to eliminate

Reporting-MTA: dns; xxxxx.xxxxxx.com

Final-Recipient: rfc822;ajkdafjhkfsd@xxxxxx.com
Action: failed
Status: 5.0.0 (permanent failure)
Remote-MTA: dns; **[192.168.92.98]**
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 5.1.0 - Unknown address error 550-"This user doesn't have a in.com account" (delivery attempts: 0)

Please help if i will be able to eliminate or strip private ip address.

Comment: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non_delivery_report

Comment: http://msg.wikidoc.info/index.php/Header_Fields_Known_to_the_MTA

Comment: http://rfc-ref.org/RFC-TEXTS/1894/kw-remote-mta.html

Answer (score 1):

Removing header information outside the guidelines in the RFC is not advisable; it seems you are bouncing this message inside your local network, after already accepting it at the edge.

You should NEVER accept mail you cannot deliver; instead, reject unknown recipients on the MX host.

Comment: And you're saying what ?

Comment: Thanks "adaptr",
As i have been going through RFC http://rfc-ref.org/RFC-TEXTS/1894/chapter2.html in the point 2.3.5 it is mentioned that the Remote-MTA field is optional.
So now how can I eliminate that from my bounce message.

Comment: That wasn't really my point - the point is that an MTA should interfere with a message's content as little as possible. Have you solved the incorrect recipient acceptance issue yet?